# Testing URL redirect with jest

Tags: redirect, jestjs, spotify

I'm trying to build a wrapper for the Spotify API, and I want to use jest to write a test for the authorization methods.

There are four [four methods of authorization](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/). Three of them send the user to a Spotify URL, ask them to authorize the app, and then redirect the user back to a provided URL. I'm using two different functions to do this: `authorizeToken` and `getToken`.

I'd like to make sure `authorizeToken is redirecting correctly and not sending the user to an error page or something. To be clear, this test would actually have to redirect to a Spotify URL and make sure it's the login page, not just an error page.

Is a test like that even possible?